# SSRS 2008 Cascading Parameters on single table

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, cascading

I'm developing and report in SSRS2008 and rather than a series of drop down parameters at the top of my page with AND/OR statements, I am looking to use Cascading Parameters.

My question is quite simple, Can I use Cascading Parameters on a **single** table?

EG

Inventory_Table:

Warehouse, Item, Price

1, Widget, $1

1, Pens, $2

1, Cards, $5

2, Popcorn, $2

2, Boxes, $10

AB, Ruler, $10

AB, Stapler, $12

So My first parameter being warehouse, if I select 1, it would return all items in Warehouse 1 (Widget, Pens, Cards).  I would then select Widget and it would return $1

In the Filters section of the dataset of "Item" after selecting Warehouse as the expression, I would only have "= , <> , Like, >=" etc

I've watched and read a few tutorials but all seem to reference multiple tables and linking the primary key, as opposed to a single table.

Please let me know if you have any thoughts or suggestions

Thanks in advance

Comment: use this link it is base on two Dataset in SSRS   http://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2014/11/ssrs-cascade-parameter-using-dataset.html

Comment: Slightly confused. You say you don't want a series of drop down's but then reference selecting a Warehouse in one Parameter and Widgets in the next, which means you would have multiple dropdowns.

Can you clarify a little exactly what you're after?

Comment: Agree your question is very confusing.   And what are you calling a table?   A database table, or a tablix on the report?

Comment: The table is a database table, called "Inventory Table" .  
EG, If I have a total of 1000 items across all warehouses, but Warehouse 1 has 100 items as opposed to Warehouse 2 which has 10, it would be much more difficult to filter when Warehouse 2 is selected. There would be presented 1000 items, 990 of which aren't present in that warehouse.